# Importing multiple files named sequentially in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have about 50 Python files in a directory, all named in a sequential order, for example: `myfile1`, `myfile2`.....`myfile50`. Now, I want to import the contents of these files inside another Python file. This is what I tried:

```
i = 0
while i < 51:
    file_name = 'myfile' + i
    import file_name
    i += 1
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named file_name
```

How may I import all these sequentially named files inside another Python file, without having to write import for each file individually?

Comment: `myfil1` through `myfile50` are all python scripts?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yes, they all are Python files.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I think Python can't do something like `import variable_name`. For example, `os = 'sys'; import os` will import `os` module.

Comment: Yes, you cannot do that using `import` statement, you would need something like `importlib` or `__import__()` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [other answer by @Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33062196/795990) is good, but simply doing - `importlib.import_module(file_name)` is not enough. As given in [the documentation of `importlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) -

> **`importlib.import_module(name, package=None)`**
>
> Import a module. The name argument specifies what module to import in absolute or relative terms (e.g. either pkg.mod or ..mod). If the name is specified in relative terms, then the package argument must be specified to the package which is to act as the anchor for resolving the package name (e.g. import_module('..mod', 'pkg.subpkg') will import pkg.mod). **The specified module will be inserted into sys.modules and returned.**

`importlib.import_module` simply returns the module object, it does not insert it into the `globals` namespace, so even if you import the module this way, you cannot later on use that module directly as `filename1.<something>` (or so).

Example -

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.import_module('a')
<module 'a' from '/path/to/a.py'>
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

To be able to use it by specifying the name, you would need to add the returned module into the `globals()` dictionary (which is the dictionary for the global namespace). Example -

```
gbl = globals()
for i in range(0, 51):
    file_name = 'myfile{}'.format(i)
    try:
        gbl[file_name] = importlib.import_module(file_name)
    except ImportError:
        pass #Or handle the error when `file_name` module does not exist.
```

It might be also be better to except `ImportError` incase `file_name` modules don't exist, you can handle them anyway you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `import` to import modules from a string containing their name. You could, however, use `importlib`:

import importlib

```
i = 0
while i < 51:
    file_name = 'myfile' + str(i)
    importlib.import_module(file_name)
    i += 1
```

Also, note that the "pythonic" way of iterating a set number of times would be to use a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(0, 51):
    file_name = 'myfile' + str(i)
    importlib.import_module(file_name)
```

Comment: This alone is not enough, this imports the module object and throws it away, you cannot directly use `myfile1.<something>` after this.

Comment: You would need to add it to `globals` dictionary with the same `file_name` as key for that to be accessible.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Can you elaborate more on this topic?

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi It would have been a bit long to explain in comments, I have added it in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Murenik and @Anand S Kumar already gave a right answers, but I just want to help a little bit too :) If you want to import all files from some folder, it's better to use `glob` function instead hardcoded `for` cycle. It's *pythonic* way to iterate across files.

```
# It's code from Anand S Kumar's solution
gbl = globals()
def force_import(module_name):
    try:
        gbl[module_name] = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    except ImportError:
        pass #Or handle the error when `module_name` module does not exist.

# Pythonic way to iterate files
import glob
for module_name in glob.glob("myfile*"):
    force_import( module_name.replace(".py", "") )
```

Comment: Cool , +1 from me, though I would prefer using `imp.load_source` for loading from full path. As explained in - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path